# How to pass arguments to a function (Q/KDB+)?

Tags: kdb, q-lang

Say I have a function:

```
quotes:{[ticker;x;y]
output: ....
}
```

How can I use this function iterate over a list in another function:

```
combiner:{[tickerList;x;y]
output: uj quotes[ticker1;x;y], quotes[ticker2;x;y], etc.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine `uj` with over `/` to do this:

```
uj/[list of tables]
```

In you case this may look like:

```
uj/[quotes[;x;y]each tickerList]
```

If the quotes function always outputs tables with the same schema you can use `raze` instead:

```
raze quotes[;x;y]each tickerList
```

`raze` and `uj` are both join functions and an implementation of `,` but `raze` requires the schema of all tables to be the same.